# installed WSL before checking "Windows Subsystem for Linux" on WIndows 11

Tags: linux, installation, windows-11, windows-subsystem-for-linux, uninstall

I installed WSL on Win 11, and Ubuntu afterwards, and everything seems to work just fine, but when I checked the tutorials how to install it, I found I had to check "Windows Subsystem for Linux" and restart then to install WSL. I did it now after installing WSL through the command line. So what did I miss, and whether everything should be Ok on Win11?

Comment: was "Windows Subsystem for LInux" checked? Can't see how WSL would work without that

Comment: Windows Subsystem for Linux is no longer installed through optional Windows features, it’s installed through the Microsoft Store, if you enable the optional feature disable it and properly install the supported version of WSL. Once you have done that [edit] your question with any updated information and remove anything that is irrelevant. Please make sure all content is grammatically correct

Comment: How did you install WSL ?

Comment: @JaromandaX I think since it worked, it was checked.